# How to maintain state across forms in windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

The main form 'A' has a link which brings on another form 'B' which the user can use to fill in multiple values.

Now on the closing of this form 'B' user can go back to the main form 'A' to select other criteria and then click on the link to bring back form 'B'. Now this form 'B' should hold the previously entered values and allow the user to add more values.

Ultimately, once the user is done, I would nee those entered values in form 'B' to be accesile from form 'A' and do what I want to do.

For now I am achieving this by having a static field on the 'B' form. I know this isn't right as the static property would remain in memory even after I close the form. Any suggestions how to do this right?

Comment: Way too broad. There would be a lot of different ways to maintain form state and there's no way to tell which one is best suited for your case without having the full blueprint for your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make public properties on Form B to hold the value you need.  Form A will then be able to access these properties via a reference to form B.

Answer (score 0):

By using MDI(Multi Document Interface) application mechanism we can achieve the solution easily.

In MDI, states were hold by the application. Whenever open the form it simply shows the previous state. It was not destroy the forms on close.This is the one method to achieve the scenario. we can achieve the functionality in many ways.